# How to move element to another parent keeping its state and DOM?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following React application:

```js
class Item extends React.PureComponent {
  state = {
    id: Math.random()
  };

  divRef = React.createRef();

  render() {
    return <div ref={this.divRef}>
      My id is {this.state.id}
    </div>;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // This is a DOM manipulation which React doesn't control. I use it to see whether React reuses the DOM element.
    const colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'navy', 'brown', 'violet'];
    const color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
    this.divRef.current.style.color = color;
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    itemPosition: 'top'
  };

  render() {
    return <React.Fragment >
      <button onClick={() => this.setState({itemPosition: 'top'})}>Move to top</button>
      <button onClick={() => this.setState({itemPosition: 'bottom'})}>Move to bottom</button>
      <div className="container">
        {this.state.itemPosition === 'top' ? <Item key="1"/> : null}
      </div>
      <div className="container">
        {this.state.itemPosition === 'bottom' ? <Item key="1"/> : null}
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

```css
.container {
  border: solid 1px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react@16.4.1/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-dom@16.4.1/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

In this example the `App` component renders an `Item` component in one of two `div`s. The `Item` component gets a random appearance every time it is mounted to detect remounting.

As you can see, the `Item` element is remounted every time it is moved to another parent `div`. Is there a way to move the element to another parent element without unmounting and mounting it to keep the element state and corresponding DOM tree?

P.S. I know I can solve the example by moving the `Item` state to its props but it is not always possible, e.g. when the DOM tree is controlled by another not-React library.

Comment: There is a similar issue in the React.js repository: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3965